# 11.04 Live CD Doesn't Work (Black Screen)

Tags: 11.04

I have burned Ubuntu 11.04 on CD then installed on Desktop PC, so this CD copy is fine, but I wanted upgrade my 10.10 (Laptop, laptop is fine,too). I have booted to Live (Try without installing) and direct install... both not working... I see just Black Screen. There are no even any processes at laptop.

Comment: Can you upgrade from the Desktop CD? I think you'll need the Alternate CD to do an upgrade.

Comment: So you do see the "Try" and "Install" options on the laptop?

Comment: @SabreWolfy, from 11.04 release you can upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04 with a normal live CD. During installation it detects existing Ubuntu and gives you the choice to upgrade.

Comment: @Chethan S.: Ok, that's new. Good to know that it's possible now.

Comment: Yes, it gives me choice "Try" and "Install". Both of them do not work. I have already tried by USB boot. Maybe there is some problem with Laptop. So, let me try same CD on another laptop where is I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 (try to upgrade this one)

Comment: rovshango - if you intend to upgrade - you'll need to do 10.04 to 10.10 to 11.04.  Dont try to short-cut this route.  If you have blackscreen issues then try to boot with "nomodeset" as a boot option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use 11.04 stable version (not beta). Bad news is unity does have video cards problem. some laptop does not load unity. I failed to install unity on a compaq laptop. Try to google this problem with your laptop model.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. I tried on another Laptop (Acer) and it worked, but on that Laptop I have installed Ubuntu 10.04.2, so I can not upgrade, I have to delete all :)

Comment: Have you tried this? when install menu appear(boot from cd) press F6 and select nomodeset. Now try to install. good luck!